# File backups when modified

Tags: backup, storage, restore

I'm trying to find something to, whenever a file is modified by a program, make a backup either in that or another folder with nameoforiginal-date or something of the like. Anyone know of something or a series of programs that could do this?

Comment: You'd think something like this would be easy, but it doesn't appear to be. You'd need a program like iwatch to watch the file for changes and then have it make a backup when it sees a change. FreeBSD has a snapshot feature, but you didn't specify OS so I assumed Linux.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Genie Timeline seemed to work, but it would insist on backing up with folders to show where it came from and overwriting the last backup, along with no feature to add dates on.

Comment: In real time?  Or scheduled?

Comment: Real time was my goal - I assume you read that Google Drive Backup and Sync worked for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive Backup and Sync seemed to work well. I set it to record versions and now I can go back 20 versions or two weeks - not the best, but it worked for what I needed it to.